# External hard drive deep freezing Macs

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk, crash

A quite nice problem:
I have an external USB 2.0 harddrive (Lacie Starck with 512GB) which was working fine during the last years. But now everytime I connect it to a Mac 3 seconds later a total crash of the system follows and the Mac needs to reboot.

I tried with OS 10.10, 10.9 and 10.6 on three different devices. All systems crashed, so it's not my Mac.

I removed the harddrive from it's case and put it into a new external case. Still crashing, so it's not the controller.

If I start the Mac into Recovery Mode and plug in the external harddrive there is again an immediate crash.

The disk itself still produces a good spinning sound but it's a killer-disk now... Problem is: I don't have any other PC with Linux or Windows and I want to get some files from the disk. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you already try another USB-cable?

Comment: yes. i tried with two different cables. it think it must best software based since the Mac crashes exactly when finder starts reading information from the disk.

Comment: Hmm then try to create a Linux Bootable thumb drive with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Choose one of the systems mentioned there. Boot from the thumb drive and check if the problem persists. If not install/use hfsplus to copy the needed files.

Comment: Additionally you may add one of the crash logs (if any exist) to your question.

Comment: If the disk is damaged, maybe it'll cause freeze when system tries to access damaged sectors. Try to connect the disk putting it on table upside down.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, when I backup a Laptop from OSX to my External HD.  Months later, I was taking the backup HD, and cloning it's content to a Sparse file via [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html).  However, randomly the process would die and the HD would act like it locked up.

For me the solution was to stop Spotlight from Scanning the HD.  This allowed me to utilize SuperDuper again, to take the image from the HD, move it to a Sparse image, which I could then backup on a NAS or offside disaster recovery, freeing the HD for other jobs.  I included the steps from an [article that helped me] to avoid future dead links.

**Exclude Specific Items from Spotlight Indexing**

> This is by far the simplest way to universally exclude something from
>   Spotlight searches and it works in all versions of Mac OS X

1. System Preferences from the  Apple menu and choose the “Spotlight” preference panel
2. Click on the “Privacy” tab
3. Drag & drop folders or drives to exclude from the Spotlight index, **or** click the “+” plus icon in the corner to manually select hard drives or directories

Result:

> Spotlight will now NOT scan your HD, thus it won't hit that corrupted
>   file or OSX unfriendly file.

Answer (score 0):

Following Matteos advice I installed Ubuntu using unetbootin on an external harddrive. It boots without any additional installation and I could access and copy the files immediately and format the external harddrive afterwards.

Now it works again also with my Mac OS so there must have been some corrupt files on it who can crash the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem as OP. In my case the issue was a **shortage of current** available to external USB 3.1 SATA 6G enclosure.

I have an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013). I'm using it with Samsung 860 Evo SSD and external Unitek DisGuard Limpid R USB 3.1 SATA 6G 2.5" disk enclosure. macOS is booted from external drive.

Initially, I experienced some random complete OS freezes followed by computer restarts. Sometimes it was happening after couple hours of normal usage, sometimes sooner, sometimes later. I was associating each freeze (and restart) with high peak of multiple demanding tasks trying to be executed.

I was using the enclosure with original USB 3.1 cable (USB A 3.1 <-> USB Micro-B 3.1) which came in the box. Fortunately, I also had another **USB 3.0 cable (Y-shaped)** with "double connector" from older external USB hard drive (USB A 3.0 + USB A 2.0 power only <-> USB Micro-B 3.0). After switching to old cable everything works fine now as expected.